# How to index an array in Repeater in Connections function QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 6.3

Page {
    width: root.width
    height: root.height
    visible: true

    background: Rectangle {
        color: "white"
    }

    Text{
        id: stageText
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        topPadding: root.height / 4
        font.pixelSize: 26
        text: ""
        color: "black"
    }

    ColumnLayout {

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        scale: root.width / 1000.0

        RowLayout{

            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
            spacing: 0

            id: visualizeRow

            property string myArr : hammingCode.getDataStr();

            Repeater {

                model: visualizeRow.myArr.length

                Rectangle {
                    id: bit

                    width: 50
                    height: 50

                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: visualizeRow.myArr.charAt(index)
                        color: "black"
                    }

                    border.width: 1
                    color: "white"
                }
            }

            Component.onCompleted: {
                stageText.text = "Encoding";
                hammingCode.encodeData(true);
            }
        }
    }

    Connections{
        target: hammingCode

        function onTurnBitOff(index){
            bit[index].color = "black";
        }

        function onTurnBitOn(index){
            bit[index].color = "red";
        }

        //put signals from c++ here that change visual stuff and shit
    }

}
```

I have a Page which using Repeater creates an array from a string of '0' and '1', it looks like this:
[Application screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eS0t.png)

What i would like to do is change the color of a certain rectangle, access a certain rectangle at given index in the Connections functions which are connected to c++ signals.

The code in the functions doesn't work (it says "bit" is undefined), but illustrates what i would like to achieve. How can this be achieved?

Comment: `bit` is not an array, you cannot access it with index. use [Repeater.itemAt()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#itemAt-method) instead. Just don't forget to add an `id` to it. but a more correct solution is using a declarative way instead of imperative one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C++ seems to offer getDataStr() as a method returning a string array. Consider changing it to a property and, reconsider the type. If your data type is an array of "1" and "0" the more efficient type for that should be just integer.

```cpp
public:
    Q_PROPERTY(int data READ data WRITE setData NOTIFY dataChanged)
    Q_INVOKABLE void setBit(int index) { setData(data() |= (1 << index)); }
    Q_INVOKABLE void clearBit(int index) { setData(data() &= ~(1 << index)); }
    Q_INVOKABLE void toggleBit(int index) { setData(data() ^= (1 << index)); }
    Q_INVOKABLE bool isSet(index) { return (data() & (1 << index)) != 0; }
signals:
    void dataChanged();
protected:
    int m_data;
    int data() const { return m_data; }
    void setData(int data) { if (m_data != data) { m_data = data; dataChanged(); } }
```

Then, you can use that to populate your Repeater and set both the text and color based on the value returned by `isSet(index)`.

In the following example, I've mocked the C++ hammingCode implementation with a `QtObject` lookalike plus I've optimized/replaced the `Repeater` with a `ListView`. Note that because the left-most top bit is bit 6, hence why you will see `6-index` math in checking the bits:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    QtObject {
        id: hammingCode
        property int data: 127
        function setBit(index) { data |= (1 << index); }
        function clearBit(index) { data &= ~(1 << index); }
        function toggleBit(index) { data ^= (1 << index); }
        function isSet(index) { return (data & (1 << index)) != 0; }
    }
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 50
        Label {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            text: qsTr("Hamming Code: %1").arg(hammingCode.data)
        }
        ListView {
            Layout.preferredWidth: 50 * 7
            Layout.preferredHeight: 50
            orientation: ListView.Horizontal
            model: 7
            delegate: Rectangle {
                property bool bitSet: hammingCode.isSet(6-index)
                property color bitColor: bitSet ? "red" : "black"
                width: 50
                height: 50
                border.color: bitColor
                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: bitSet ? "1" : "0"
                    color: bitColor
                }
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: hammingCode.toggleBit(6-index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)